# How to print an input using the print function? (It should allow the user to type)

Tags: python

How do i print an input using the print function? (it should allow the user to type)

```
 if ChooseGame=="1":
    part1story = input("Do you want to skip the story[y] or [n]")

if part1story=="y":
   robotwarpart1()
```

As you can see, the robotwarpart1 function will only be called if we give input to part1story. Yes i know, my code should just work fine, but i get this error: (I'm using replit python)

NameError: Name part1story is not defined.

Comment: If `ChooseGame` is not `"1"`, `part1story` is not defined.

Comment: honestly i dont understand what are you asking about?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ChooseGame is 1(in the console)

Comment: Might it be that it's really `1` and not `"1"`?

Answer (score 1):

your code should look like:

```py
part1story = 'n'
if ChooseGame == '1':
  part1story = input("Do you want to skip the story[y] or [n]")

if part1story == 'y':
  robotwarpart1()
```

You get a `NameError` because as the comment mentions, `part1story` isn't even getting defined if `ChooseGame` is not `"1"`.

Comment: the choose game is 1

Comment: @Stickpion maybe then as @Jonas V mentioned, the ChooseGame might be `1` and not `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @esskayesss said so, you need to define the variable in a wider scope, because the way you did it, the variable 'part1story' was only accessible inside the if statement.

Also, in your case, if `ChooseGame` is not "1" (which is a string here!), you simply won't give a value to it, hence it returns false at the second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
if ChooseGame == '1':
    part1story = input("Do you want to skip the story[y] or [n]")
    if part1story == 'y':
        robotwarpart1()
```

So make less conditions.